# How to selectively disable cookies?

Tags: 7, cookies

We have a drupal 7 instances and were wondering how it would be possible to conditionally disable certain cookies for site visitors? We are trying to make sure we are EU cookie compliant. We are currently using [EU Cookie Compliance](http://protiviti.prod.dd:8083/) module, but that is not sufficient enough as we have other cookies that we are using on our site. What are some ways to provide an option to opt out of certain cookies?

Comment: If you are you talking about Drupal-specific cookies like the user cookie, then I dont think you can remove them because that's how the user session is tracked. For all other cookies can be managed with PHP cookie, see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: @longboardnode no this is for other tracking cookies like Marketo or Google Analytics.

Comment: Are you using the tracking code module or any other snippet module to generate these cookies? Or just embedding the JS in the page?